# EditForm - How can I prevent submit on pressing enter key

Tags: blazor

I've found [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-core-3-1-preview-2/) but I'm having a hard time to understand how can I prevent submit on "enter" key independently by any `<input>`

```html
<EditForm Model="exampleModel" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <InputText id="name" @bind-Value="exampleModel.Name" />
    <InputText id="name2" @bind-Value="exampleModel.Name2" />

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>
```

```cs
@code {
    private ExampleModel exampleModel = new ExampleModel();

    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnValidSubmit");
    }

    public class ExampleModel
    {
         [Required]
         [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Name is too long.")]
         public string Name { get; set; }
         public string Name2 {get; set;}
    }
}
```

### Use Case

> Enter key On HTML forms if you are filling out a text box and press the enter key it will submit the form, even if you haven't finished filling in the rest of the information. There are many websites which use this feature such as Google search box will submit when you press the enter key. This works because you only have one text box to fill out, but if there are more than one field to fill in you don't want the form to submit on the enter key.

Comment: I've already seen that question before write mine. I decided to write a new one because place two submit button inside a form it does not seem to be a good solution but just a workaround that works for some reason. Anyway, @enet I've tried your solution but if I press "enter" multiple times, there is one case where the form still run the submission

Comment: Having two submit buttons in a single form is nonsensical clowning, not programming. It  definitely does not fall in what workaround means. I've run my code again, and it never allows submission to take place, as long as the submit  button has the input focus and you press the Enter key. If another control, say a textbox, has the input focus, and you hit the Enter key, then of course the submission action would take place, provided that your data is valid.

Comment: I agree with you enet. This is why I open a new question. There is a meaning behind the question title "edit form - ..." Because I want to prevent it from any input contained inside the edit form.

Comment: I understand you... I'll look for a solution to this if I can. Ask to reopen your question. There is no reason for it to be closed.

Comment: Leonardo Lurci, I'm sorry but I think this cannot currently be done in Blazor unless you resort to JSInterop. I looked for some help in github, but to no avail. The Blazor team members redirect users with similar questions to stackoverflow. This feature is greatly important, and I hope a solution to it may be provided by the Blazor team...

Comment: did you check <button type="button" @onclick="EVENTHANDLER" ...>

Comment: Just a side remark : when you don't set the type of a button (even out of `EditForm`), the button gets the `submit` standard behaviour (button is clicked when you press enter). To prevent it, you have to specify the button type `type="button"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Leonardo Lurci, here's a complete solution implemented purely in C#, no JSInterop. As it turned out, Microsoft has already provided this feature, but they did not provide enough samples to demonstrate how to use it.

As it turned out, I cannot use the pair `@onkeypress="@KeyHandler"` and                             `@onkeypress:preventDefault` with the Forms components such as InputText, but applying these directives to Html tags is viable and works perfectly well. See for instance how I apply these directives to the "submit" button.

Consequently, I subclass the base class InputBase, this is the class from which the InputText components derive, overrides the default view rendering by adding an input element to which I can add the directives of the new feature.

TextBox.razor (this comes instead of InputText)

```cs
    @inherits InputBase<string>

    <input type="text" value="@CurrentValueAsString" id="Id" class="@CssClass" 
       @onkeydown="KeyDownHandler" @onkeypress="KeyPressHandler" 
                                                   @onkeypress:preventDefault/>

     @code{

    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string value, out string 
                                      result, out string validationErrorMessage)
    {
        result = value;
        validationErrorMessage = null;
        return true;
    }

    void KeyDownHandler(KeyboardEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Key == "Backspace" && CurrentValueAsString.Length >=1)
        {
            CurrentValueAsString = CurrentValueAsString.Substring(0, 
                                       CurrentValueAsString.Length - 1);
        }
    }

     void KeyPressHandler(KeyboardEventArgs args)
     {

        if (args.Key == "Enter")
        {
            return;
        }
        var key = (string)args.Key;
        CurrentValueAsString += key;
     }
    }
```

Usage

```html
    <p>Leave me a comment</p>

    <EditForm Model="Model" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit" >
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />

     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name: </label>
        <TextBox Id="name" Class="form-control" @bind-Value="@Model.Name" >
        </TextBox>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Model.Name)" />

     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="body">Text: </label>
        <InputTextArea Id="body" Class="form-control" @bind-Value="@Model.Text" > 
        </InputTextArea>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Model.Text)" />
     </div>
     <p>
        <button type="submit" @onkeypress="KeyHandler" @onkeypress:preventDefault>
            Submit
        </button>
     </p>
    </EditForm>


    @code
    {
        private Comment Model = new Comment();

        private void HandleValidSubmit()
        {
             Console.WriteLine("Submit...");
        }


        void KeyHandler(KeyboardEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Key == "Enter")
            {
               return;
             }
        }

        public class Comment
        {
            public string Name { get; set; } = "Jeff";
            public string Text { get; set; } = "I'm Jeff. I'm from Canada";
        }

    }
```

Please, don't hesitate to ask any questions

Hope this helps...

Comment: what if the focused element is a 3rd party control?

Answer (score 6):

Add event handlers to your input and submit elements like this:

```html
<InputText id="name" @bind-Value="exampleModel.Name" @onkeydown="PreventSubmit"/>
<button type="submit" @onclick="ShouldISubmit">Submit</button>
```

Add this to your @code block:

```cs
public bool shouldsubmit { get; set; }

public bool entersubmit { get; set; }

public void PreventSubmit(KeyboardEventArgs ev)
{
    if (ev.Key == "Enter")
        entersubmit = true;
}

public void ShouldISubmit()
{
    if (entersubmit)
        shouldsubmit = false;
    else
        shouldsubmit = true;
    entersubmit = false;
}
```

Change your submit function to this

```cs
private void HandleValidSubmit()
{
    if (shouldsubmit) {
        Console.WriteLine("OnValidSubmit");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As Enet suggested in the comments, there isn't a full Blazor (Csharp) solution for this use-case. You have to interact with JavaScript.

Currently, I solved with this workaround:

blazor-side

```html
@inject IJSRuntime JS
<EditForm id="askQuestionForm" Model="exampleModel" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <InputText id="name" @bind-Value="exampleModel.Name" />
    <InputText id="name2" @bind-Value="exampleModel.Name2" />

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>
```

```cs
@code {
    private ExampleModel exampleModel = new ExampleModel();

    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnValidSubmit");
    }

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender) 
        {
            JS.InvokeVoidAsync("PreventEnterKey", "askQuestionForm");
        }
    }

    public class ExampleModel
    {
         [Required]
         [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Name is too long.")]
         public string Name { get; set; }
         public string Name2 {get; set;}
    }
}
```

interop.js

```js
function PreventEnterKey(id) {
    $(`#${id}`).keydown(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

I hope Microsoft will develop this feature in the future.

Thanks to Enet.

Answer (score 2):

I found a simple solution that I think is the easiest option.
Create a custom component that will be your submit button:

```
<button type="button" @onclick="OnClick" @attributes="UnmatchedAttributes">@Text</button>


@code {

    [Parameter]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Func<Task> OnValidSubmitAsync { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Action OnValidSubmit { get; set; }

    [CascadingParameter]
    public EditContext EditContext { get; set; }

    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
    public Dictionary<string, object> UnmatchedAttributes { get; set; }

    private async Task OnClick() {
        if (EditContext != null) {
            if (EditContext.Validate()) {
                if (OnValidSubmit != null) {
                    OnValidSubmit();
                } else {
                    if (OnValidSubmitAsync != null) {
                        await OnValidSubmitAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This component acts as a submit button, but since its type is not submit, an enter won't trigger it. It accepts a cascading parameter of type EditContext which allows it to validate the form. It also accepts a delegate which will be triggered when it is clicked and the form state is valid.

Usage example:

```
<EditForm Model="model">
    <input type="text" @bind="model.Value" />
    @* Add the custom submit component*@
    <EditFormSubmit Text="Submit" OnValidSubmit="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"></EditFormSubmit> 
</EditForm>
```

Comment: Love the idea, Michael! I just posted a slightly modified version of your answer that simplifies your logic and expands the usability of the component :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/74514709/5358731

Answer (score 1):

First you should understand how browsers behaves in this case.
If there is a `<button type="submit">` in the form, and user presses enter, the browser will emulate `click` event on the button.

Rather then cancelling the keypress event you can prevent the click event using  `addEventListener` with `capture: true`.

Just add following javascript:

```
//prevent submit on enter
document.body.addEventListener('keypress', e => {
    if (e.which == ENTER && !e.target.matches('button[type=submit]')) {

        /** @type {HTMLFormElement} */
        const form = e.composedPath().find(e => e.matches('form'))

        /** @type {HTMLButtonElement} */
        const submitButton = form && form.querySelector('button[type=submit]:enabled');

        if (submitButton) {
            const preventSubmit = (e2) => {
                e2.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
            // Browser emulates submit button click, when enter key is pressed, so we need to prevent that.
            form.addEventListener('click', preventSubmit, { once: true, capture: true });
            setTimeout(() => form.removeEventListener('click', preventSubmit, { capture: true }), 0); // better clear the eventlistener despite once:true in case the keypress propagation has been stopped by some other eventhandler
        }
        
    }
});
```

It works in Blazor Server and Blazor WebAssembly and you don't need to touch your exiting code.

Demo here: https://blazorrepl.com/repl/mvYgPhPx007ySOGe03

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. Fairly lean code, no js. This way, you're not directly preventing the default behavior of the Enter key. Instead, you're controlling whether the form should proceed with submission based on the Enter key event.

In your EditForm declaration

```
<EditForm OnValidSubmit="@Submit" @onkeydown="HandleKeyDown">
```

In your code:

```
private bool allowFormSubmit = true;
protected void HandleKeyDown(KeyboardEventArgs args)
{
    allowFormSubmit = !(args.Key == "Enter");
}

protected async Task Submit()
{
   //consume the Enter key and reset to allow form submission on submit click
   if (!allowFormSubmit)
   {
      allowFormSubmit = true;
      return;
   }
   //Your submit code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So as discussed in other answers, the browser will automatically "click" a submit button if one is available when the enter key is pressed unless you use JS to prevent it, or add event handlers to EACH text box to prevent it.

I expanded on [Michael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69123227/5358731) and created a more flexible "submit" button to work around the standard submit behavior. Note: **this will make your form a little less accessibility-friendly**. Please consider if this solution is appropriate for your project.

**SubmitButton.razor**

```
<button type="button" @onclick="OnClick" @attributes="UnmatchedAttributes">@ChildContent</button>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback OnValidSubmit { get; set; }

    [CascadingParameter]
    public EditContext? EditContext { get; set; }

    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
    public Dictionary<string, object>? UnmatchedAttributes { get; set; }

    private async Task OnClick()
    {
        if (EditContext != null && EditContext.Validate())
        {
            await OnValidSubmit.InvokeAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage** (example with Bootstrap classes & FontAwesome icons)

```
<EditForm Model="@model">
    @* Add your form elements *@
    <SubmitButton class="btn btn-success" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit"><i class="fas fa-save me-2"></i>Submit</SubmitButton>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private async Task HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        // Do your thing!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: it seems you need another `@onkeypress` on the page.

I have to admit the following is a bit more complicated than the original solution... but it works  sorry for the missleading information.

```
<EditForm Model="exampleModel" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit" @onkeypress:preventDefault="preventDefault">
    <InputText @bind-Value="exampleModel.Name1" @onkeypress="@(e => preventDefault = e.Key == "Enter")" />

    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    public bool preventDefault { get; set; } = false;
}
```

---

---

Bit late but figured out that

`@onkeydown:preventDefault="true"`

in your EditForm Component will also do the trick.

```
<EditForm Model="exampleModel" @onkeydown:preventDefault="true" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <InputText id="name" @bind-Value="exampleModel.Name" />
    <InputText id="name2" @bind-Value="exampleModel.Name2" />

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>
```

Comment: Sadly this seemingly simple solution did not work for me, after an enter press the OnValidSubmit method was called.

Comment: @devbf you are correct sorry. Tried this in a blank new solution and couldn't replicate the behavior.
I'll take a look, what I did diffrent in the working solution :)

Comment: @devbf sorry, I missed a few crutial parts in my code, that's why it didn't work. `@onkeydown:preventDefault` requires a registered `@onkeydown` event and blocks all default behavior. Even entering something in your input field. Thats why I added the lambda expression which checks, if the key pressed is the Enter key.

Answer (score -1):

**A Keep It Simple approach:**

1. Add an item to your Item's class definition, for WhatToDo:

   ```
   public string WhatToDo { get; set; }
   ```
2. Add an invisible button as the first button in your submit buttons, and
3. Test for its value in your OnSubmit method.  If the user just presses Enter, the value of this button will be returned.

If it's value is (in my case "DoNothing") then simply return.

```
<EditForm..... with OnSubmit parameters>
...

   <button type="submit" @onclick="@(()=> selectedItem.WhatToDo = "DoNothing")" class="btn btn-primary" style="display:none;">Do Nothing</button>
    <button type="submit" @onclick="@(()=> selectedItem.WhatToDo = "Save")" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    <button type="submit" @onclick="@(()=> selectedItem.WhatToDo = "ExitWOSave")" class="btn btn-primary">Exit w/o Saving</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
  private async Task InsertOrUpdateItem()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("WhatToDo is XX" + selectedItem.WhatToDo + "XX");

        if (selectedItem.WhatToDo == "ExitWOSave")   //test for this first
        {
            // Navigate away…
            return;
        };

        if (selectedItem.WhatToDo == "DoNothing")
        { return; }

        if (selectedItem.WhatToDo == "Save")
        { //do your save…
    return; 
}

}
```