# Blazor InputText trigger function with Enter button

Tags: blazor-webassembly

```
    <EditForm class="form-inline col-md-12 p-3" Model="searcher" OnValidSubmit="OnSearchSubmit">
    <input class="form-control w-100 mr-3"
           type="text"
           @bind-value="searcher.SearchText"
           @onkeypress="KeyHandler"
           placeholder="Enter employee name to filter" />
    <ValidationMessage For="()=> searcher.SearchText" />
    <div class="mx-auto mt-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-3">Search</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary " @onclick="ShowEmployeeList" @onclick:stopPropagation="true">Reset</button>
    </div>

</EditForm>

   //Function
    private async Task KeyHandler(KeyboardEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == "Enter")
    {
        await OnSearchSubmit();

    }

}
```

I am attempting to have a function run When I press the Enter key in an `InputText` box, but so far the behaviour I observed is that of the first `button` element within then `EditForm` being fired upon pressing Enter. Is there a work around for this?

Comment: Have you tried this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62054672/editform-how-can-i-prevent-submit-on-pressing-enter-key/62103477#62103477

Comment: Will definitely look into that, thanks

Comment: Ive tried enet's solution.  It works, but it only appends to the end of the input value.  You'll probably need to get selectionstart and selectionend from JSInterop to make it work like you want.

Comment: @Sisyphus I see, so basically i rearranged the order of the buttons and put the submit button first so when enter was pressed it would send for now. I will have to consider that selection start and end, might be too much time investment for what I want.

Answer (score 2):

The button type is 'submit' here so it by defaults submits the form and triggers 'OnSearchSubmit' function. To avoid this, you can change the button type to 'button'.

I hope it helps!