# Blazor MatAutocompletelist throwing System.ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web-applications, blazor, matblazor

I'm building hotel service web application and I'm want to use MatBlazor component called MatAutocompleteList for choosing clients for reservations I've encountered an issue when Client is selected like on the screen

[image]

And I remove this value leaving it blank and press enter application throws an exception:
[image]

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'model')
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.FieldIdentifier..ctor(Object model, String fieldName)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.FieldIdentifier.Create[TField](Expression`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.ValidationMessage`1.OnParametersSet()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallOnParametersSetAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SetDirectParameters(ParameterView parameters)
```

Heres the usage of a component:

```cs
@using HotelServiceSystem.Entities
@using HotelServiceSystem.Features
@using HotelServiceSystem.Interfaces.Services
@using HotelServiceSystem.Core
@inject IHotelReservationService hotelReservationService
@inject IClientService clientService
@inject IRoomService roomService

<EditForm Model="@ReservationModel" OnValidSubmit="@SaveReservation">
    <FluentValidationValidator/>
    @if (ClientList != null && ClientList.Any())
    {
            <MatAutocompleteList Items="@ClientList.ToArray()" TItem="Client" CustomStringSelector="@(i => i.FirstName + " " + i.LastName)" Label="Choose client" @bind-Value="@ReservationModel.Client" FullWidth="@true" ShowClearButton="@true">
                <ItemTemplate Context="template">
                    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; width: 100%;">
                        <div>@template.FirstName @template.LastName @template.PhoneNumber</div>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </MatAutocompleteList>
    }
    else
    {
        <p>First u need to add clients</p>
    }
    <ValidationMessage For="@(()=> ReservationModel.Client.Id)"></ValidationMessage>
    <HssInputCustom Caption="Number of guests" @bind-Value="ReservationModel.NumberOfGuests"/>
    <div class="col-12 row">
        <label class="col-2">Date From</label>
        <MatDatePicker class="form-control col-3" @bind-Value="ReservationModel.DateFrom"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 row">
        <label class="col-2">Date to</label>
        <MatDatePicker class="form-control col-3" @bind-Value="ReservationModel.DateTo"/>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => ReservationModel.DateTo)"></ValidationMessage>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <HSSMultiSelector Selected="@_selected" NotSelected="@_notSelected"/>
    </div>
    <HssInputCustom Caption="Price" @bind-Value="ReservationModel.Price"/>
    <HssInputCustom Caption="Discount" @bind-Value="ReservationModel.Discount"/>
    <div class="col-12 row">
        <span class="col-2"></span>
        <input type="submit" class="form-control col-1 btn btn-primary" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private HotelReservation ReservationModel { get; set; }
    private readonly List<MultiSelector> _selected = new List<MultiSelector>();
    private List<MultiSelector> _notSelected = new List<MultiSelector>();
    private List<Room> _selectedRooms = new List<Room>();
    private List<Room> RoomList { get; set; }
    private List<Client> ClientList { get; set; }
    private List<string> ClientIdList { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<HotelReservation> OnReservationAdd { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        RoomList = roomService.GetAllRoomsAsync();
        ClientList = clientService.GetAllClients();
        ReservationModel = new HotelReservation {Client = new Client()};
        _notSelected = RoomList.Select(x => new MultiSelector(x.Id.ToString(), $"Room Number : {x.RoomIdentifier}")).ToList();
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
    

    private async Task SaveReservation()
    {
        _selectedRooms = RoomList.Where(x => _selected.Any(y => y.Key == x.Id.ToString())).ToList();

        _selectedRooms.ForEach( x=> ReservationModel.RoomReservations.Add(new RoomReservation
        {
            Reservation = ReservationModel,
            Room = x
        }));

        await hotelReservationService.AddHotelReservationAsync(ReservationModel);
        await OnReservationAdd.InvokeAsync(ReservationModel);
        ReservationModel = new HotelReservation() {Client = new Client()};
    }
}
```

Also my model to which I'm binding value is created properly.

```
 private Client _selectedClient = new Client();
```

I've no clue how I can prevent user from doing that, or if I can somehow catch this exception. Maybe someone had a similar issue. Much appriciate help!

Comment: "and press enter"...here's the issue. Post more context please.

Comment: @enet I could either press enter or click out of this control and then this exception occurs

Comment: Let me guess...your code is within an EditForm component, right ? When the user press the enter key,  a post request takes place, whether you use an EditForm or not... The issue is that hitting the enter key triggers the submission of the  form. Now, if you want your patient be treated, please show him.

Comment: @enet EditForm is not the issue right here I have tested it. It also happends when I'm leaving blank space and click out ot this form, then exception throws

Comment: Without seeing your code nothing further can be said...

Comment: @enet Added whole page, thanks for your support

Comment: Please read my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62054672/editform-how-can-i-prevent-submit-on-pressing-enter-key

Comment: @enet That is still not resolving my problem as this is also occuring when I'm leaving this control blank and click outside of this control

Comment: Last resort: Upload your app into gitub and post here a link. I'll download and run it to see what the issue. If you can't do that, I'm afraid that you'll have to wait until someone else may discern the issue.

Comment: @enet Right now I've fixed this issue by using different autocomplete component, I really appriciate your effort. For now I will just leave this as it is. I've also reported this as a issue to author of this component. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to resolve this issue in simple way. I've created property for my model client object and in this propery I've created a null check

```cs
private Client _selectedClient
{
    get
    {
        if (ReservationModel.Client == null)
        {
            return new Client()
            {
                CompanyName = "",
                Email = "",
                FirstName = "",
                LastName = "",
                PhoneNumber = "",
                Id = 0
            };
        }

        return ReservationModel.Client;

    }
    set => ReservationModel.Client = value;
}
```

and now in code im calling property to set and get value for my model.