# Blazor Blazored.Typeahead component throws exception after clearing textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web-applications, blazor, blazored

Hi I'm trying to resolve this issue for some time and nothing seems to be working
I've BazloredTypeahead component used in my project. I'm biding object from my model and I'm using template to get my object string representation

Heres some representation of my code:

```cs
<EditForm Model="@ReservationModel" OnValidSubmit="@Submit">
    <FluentValidationValidator/>
    @if (ClientList != null && ClientList.Any())
    {
        <BlazoredTypeahead SearchMethod="ClientSearch" @bind-Value="ReservationModel.Client" >
            <SelectedTemplate Context="template">
                @template.GetAutocompleteValue()
            </SelectedTemplate>
            <ResultTemplate Context="template">
                @template.GetAutocompleteValue()
            </ResultTemplate>
            <NotFoundTemplate>
                Client not found
            </NotFoundTemplate>
        </BlazoredTypeahead>
    }
    <br/>
        <div class="col-12 row">
        <span class="col-2"></span>
        <input type="submit" class="form-control col-2 btn btn-primary" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
</EditForm>
```

This component has a clear icon as default and every time I clicked it I got this exception.

[image]

```cs
Error: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'model')
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.FieldIdentifier..ctor(Object model, String fieldName)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.FieldIdentifier.Create[TField](Expression`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.ValidationMessage`1.OnParametersSet()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallOnParametersSetAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SetDirectParameters(ParameterView parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.UpdateRetainedChildComponent(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldComponentIndex, Int32 newComponentIndex)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForFramesWithSameSequence(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldFrameIndex, Int32 newFrameIndex)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForFramesWithSameSequence(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldFrameIndex, Int32 newFrameIndex)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.ComputeDiff(Renderer renderer, RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, Int32 componentId, ArrayRange`1 oldTree, ArrayRange`1 newTree)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderInExistingBatch(RenderQueueEntry renderQueueEntry)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
e.log @ blazor.server.js:19
```

I'm sure that my objects are not null initially.

My GetAutocompleteValue method:

```cs
    public static string GetAutocompleteValue(this Client client)
    {
        return client == null ? string.Empty : $"{client.FirstName} {client.LastName} - {client.PhoneNumber}";
    }
```

So everything is working untill I click "X". I had same issue with different component ([old issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65540136/blazor-matautocompletelist-throwing-system-argumentnullexception)) but it seems that exception is following me :( I will appriciate any help.

Comment: I've found solution and described it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65540136/blazor-matautocompletelist-throwing-system-argumentnullexception)